# ngOptions - Value Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS and I've generated an object with a `size` property that holds an array of objects.

```js
var product = [
  // ..
  sizes: [
    {choice: 'one', order: 1},
    {choice: 'two', order: 2},
    {choice: 'three', order: 3}
  ]
  //..
];
```

On the view side I generate the select box like:

```html
<select ng-init="size = product.sizes[0]" ng-options="size.choice for size in product.sizes" ng-model="size"></select>
```

This works but when I create a button to get the current selected value of the select it returns undefined: `alert($scope.size);`

I've duplicated the problem **[here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPdEZX?editors=101)** Also just for giggles I recreated the same thing (?) in another CodePen **[here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbepdG?editors=101)**

The second one works the way I want it to but not the first. I made both but I cannot figure out why the second works and the first does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a classic problem in angular. Its because you are using ng-if which is creating a child scope. you need to set your model to someObject.size and change all references to that. 
And then in the controller put $scope.someObject = {};

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ng-show or ng-hide to avoid creating the extra scope

Comment: @Vlad274 changing to `ng-show` worked. jw, I guess I don't really follow the child scope. Can you create an example?

Comment: I guess you could picture it as when you use ng-if you are creating another controller at that point. A "hidden" angular based controller. So the size model exists in that controller, not in your "prod" controller. If you want the "hidden" controller to transfer that model up to your "prod" controller you need to use dot notation as is recommended by angular creators. ng-model should always have something.somethingelse

Comment: @jw56578 thanks for the help but just to double check this is what you're talking about? [CopePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPdEZX?editors=101)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i'm talking about.

Comment: Awesome much appreciated.